# Can't change value of slider control to 0

Tags: excel, forms, vba, slider

So I have a form with some sliders on it, as well as some corresponding checkboxes that disable or enable each slider. When I disable a slider, I want to change its value to 0, but it refuses to cooperate and won't change the value. Frustratingly, as long as I'm setting the value to something besides 0, it will change.

I've debugged it, watched a slider's `Value` property change for values greater than 0, verified that the controls in the `sliders` array corresponded to the controls I intended them to, verified that the `Min` property was 0 and even changed it to an absurdly low number on the off chance it wasn't inclusive, so I can't imagine why it'd behave this way.

It's actually not terribly important since a slider's value isn't counted when it's disabled, but it is bugging the hell out of me, so I'd appreciate any insight on this.

```
Private Sub UpdateSliderComponents(i As Integer)
    Dim enable As Boolean
    enable = Not daysOff(i).Value

    If Not enable Then
        sliders(i).Value = 0
    End If
    labels(i).Enabled = enable
    sliders(i).Enabled = enable
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out a simple form here in the attempt of reproducing your case. But it's not the same and the controls work fine.

Also do note that Min and Max aren't really what you think as 0 and 100. It's the range of the values. Value is another property. I can set Min as 150 and Max as 300. Value 150 now represent the **zero point** (0 percent) of the slider and 300 represent the so called 100 percent in that case. If you have set Min to be 150 and then tried to set the value to be 0, that will cause you an error. (*Run-time error 380, could not set the Value property. Invalid property value.*)

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Respond(ByRef i As Integer)
Dim enable As Boolean

Select Case i
    Case 0
        enable = False
    Case 1
        enable = True
End Select

If Not enable Then
    ScrollBar1.Value = 150 '--represents zero %
    ScrollBar1.BackColor = &H8000000F
Else
    ScrollBar1.Value = 250 '--represent some value in the range
    ScrollBar1.BackColor = &H80FF80
End If

Debug.Print ScrollBar1.Value
ScrollBar1.Enabled = enable

End Sub
```

Tick and slides to 250 (some value):

[image]

Untick and slides to 150 (zero):

[image]